# How to interpret fractions as numbers in sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

How do I convert a column of strings like `1/2` and `2/3` into decimal numbers like `0.5` and `0.666`?

For example, can I force the entire column to be evaluated as formulas, without needing to prepend `=` in each cell individually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Option 1

**Convert "fractions" into numbers in another column**

You can convert text strings like `1/2` and `2/3` in column `A2:A` into decimal numbers like `0.5` and `0.666` like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  iferror( 
    regexextract(trim(A2:A), "^(\d+)") 
    / 
    regexextract(trim(A2:A), "(\d+)$") 
  ) 
)
```

Place the formula in row 2 of a free column. The new column will contains the converted values, and the source text strings will remain unchanged.

### Option 2

**Unpack the numerators and denominators in "fractions" into their own columns**

To split the numerators into one column, and denominators into another column, use this formula in row 2 of a free column with another free column available immediately in the right:

```
=arrayformula( iferror( split(trim(A2:A), "/", false, true) ) )
```

To calculate the quotients of the numerators and denominators, use a formula like `=arrayformula( iferror(I2:I / J2:J) )` where `I2:J` are the new columns.

### Option 3

**Convert "fractions" into formulas in place**

In the general case, there is not much point to try and implement a parser to evaluate a text string as a spreadsheet formula. It is much easier to use the initial `=` and let Google Sheets do the hard lifting.

To *permanently* convert text strings like `1/2` and `2/3` into formulas like `=1/2` and `=2/3` that return decimal numbers like `0.5` and `0.666`, replacing the values *in place*, use **Edit > Find and replace**:

Find: `^(\d+/\d+)$`
Replace with: `=$1`
Search: `This sheet`
☑️ Match case
☑️ Search using regular expressions
**<kbd>Replace all</kbd>**

Comment: Is there no way to unpack function arguments from an array, as in `=DIVIDE(*SPLIT(A1, "/"))`?

Comment: Manually adding the `=` to each successive cell is cumbersome if a long table of data (students scores) has already been tabulated in this number format (i.e. as fractions).

Comment: The last option is by far the best IMHO